Compare frequencies - which approach? (Excel-based)
I'd like to check if two groups differ significantly in proportions.
To make this more concrete: I have sub-group A that represents X% of group 1, and sub-group B that represents Y% of another group 2. Speaking in data, I know the two percentages of sub-group A and B as well as the sample sizes for groups 1 and 2.
How do I proceed statistically? As far as I could figure out, I could go for both z-test for difference in proportions and for calculating the confidence interval of the difference (to check if 0 is included). Which of these approaches would be more adequate? And how could I calculate them in Excel? I got some results, however this entailed multiple steps and as I would need to run these comparisons for a large amount of groups, I'd prefer having the entire formula in one cell.
Any input is greatly appreciated.

What do you mean by "represents X% of group 1"? You take a sample which is, e.g. 5% of the total population of group 1? And what do you measure on this sample A? You talk about proportions, but proportion of what? Could you clarify the question?

Apologies for being unspecific on that. I have a sample of participants and check for the channel they were recruited - e.g. 5% of the total sample were recruited via phone. The survey took part two times, hence there are 2 samples (independent, no participants being in both) with each a sub-sample of phone-recruited participants. I would like to check if the difference in phone-recruitments is significant.

It may be better to modify your question, to add the clarifications; not all contributors read all the comments...

Given the sizes of groups 1 and 2, plus the percentages that your sub-groups of interest make up of these groups, you can set up a contingency table.
Then this is a textbook case where a chi squared test is appropriate, either Pearson's for a large sample size or Fisher's exact test for small cell counts. This choice will depend on your situation.
There are many tutorials on the internet on how to perform such a test in Excel.

If I understand correctly, you have 2 independent samples (your Group1, and Group2). In each sample, there is a certain proportion of subjects (your participants) which have a specific attribute (in your case, how they were recruited). You want to know if the difference in this proportion, between the 2 samples is statistically different (or could be due to sampling errors)?
One option is to use a 2-sample z test of proportions. You can find an online calculator here. For the z-test, you need the proportions and sample sizes.
Another option is to use a 2x2 contingency table, and use either a Fisher-exact or a $\chi^2$ test. You should use the Fisher-exact method if the observed proportions are "extreme" (either close to 0 or 1), because in that case the normal approximation on which z and $chi^2$ tests are based does not hold. How close to 0 or 1? Below 5-10% (or above 90-95%). You can find an online calculator for both here. Note that the p-value you will get for the z-test and $chi^2$ test will be exactly the same (as, in this case, the $chi^2$ statistic is exactly the square of the z stastistic). For the contingency table, you need the counts of subjects the attribute, and of those who do not.
Since you want to do this in Excel, the simplest is to use the z-test (which is readily available in Excel). But if the conditions for a normal approximation are not met, you will have to use Fisher-exact, which is not built-in. But, you can use the Real Statistics add-on (and excellent, and free add-on, with lots of statistical tools); see here.
Now, I assume that you are comparing these 2 proportons to ascertain if the 2 samples (Group1 and Group2) are "comparable" (is their composition similar "enough"). If the test is statistically significant, then you would claim that they are not. But if the test is not statistically significant, you can not claim that they are "similar". It could simply be because your test did not have the necessary power (e.g. if your counts of subjects with the attribute are quite small). And I am a little concerned that this (the 2 groups are similar) is what you are trying to "prove". And comparing the 2 proportions can not do that...
